# How to create auto redirect to 301 https + proxy_pass in NGINX for one location /

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, certbot, angular

This is my nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  server_tokens off;

  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /var/www/certbot;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://frontend:4200;
#     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://backend:8080;
    rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1 break;
  }
}
```

How to creacte both: redirect to 301 https://$host$request_uri; and proxy_pass http://frontend:4200;

If uncomment this string #     return 301 https://$host$request_uri; I see only redirect.

Comment: Please add more information to your question by editing it: 1. Should both "backend" and "frontend" be reachable from public internet? If yes, why backend traffic is not encrypted? 2. Is either "frontend" or "backend" located in "localhost"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to serve your backend only via HTTPS, then you need to define your backend in HTTPS server block, for example like this:

```
# HTTP server for redirect
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS server for application
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/example.com.key;
    server_name example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend:4200;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://backend:8080;
        rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1 break;
    }
}
```